# Change work hours in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-designer, visual-studio, sharepoint-online, office-365

I want to change hours work in sharepoint online. I have found something like that: http://jamestsai.net/Blog/post/How-to-change-SharePoint-Calendar-default-start-hour-and-end-hour-of-Day-View.aspx

Can I use this solution on SharePoint Online?

If yes, how can I use this on SP Online?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regional settings are available in Site Settings normally, I can't speak to O365.  You shouldn't need to use managed code to update that.